# how to insert multiple commands into a prepared statement

Tags: r, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

The problem is that putting queries together, I got this "error: cannot insert multiple commands into a prepared statement". What can I do?

```
q1="
    set search_path to care;
    SELECT COALESCE(c.date,a.date,jq.date,jn.date) reportmonth,registration,emailverified,application,submitted,eligible,jqtest,selected,joined
    from      ( SELECT date_trunc('month', createdon)::date as date, count(1) as registration,count(case when emailverified='Yes'then 1 end) as emailverified from contact group by 1)
    full join ( SELECT date_trunc('month', timecreated)::date as date, count(1) as joined from scholars where deleted='FALSE' group by 1 ) jn on jn.date=c.date
    order by 1;"

funnel=dbGetQuery(prod,q1)
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear: The driver/API you are using won't allow multiple statements.  Break into separate statements.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am new to writing queries. Could you suggest or help with breaking this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try omitting the `'set search_path to talentcare;'` part from your `dbGetQuery`. `dbGetQuery` only works with `SELECT` (or `SELECT`-like) queries. You can move the `'set search path'` to a seperate `dbExecute()` statement.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that.

In your case, a simple solution would be to get rid of the `SET` statement and run a single `SELECT`, where you qualify all tables with the schema name.

For other cases, an alternative is to create a PL/pgSQL function with the statements in it:

```
CREATE FUNCTION mystmt() RETURNS TABLE (date, ...)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
SET search_path = talentcare AS
$$BEGIN
   RETURN SELECT ...;
END;$$;
```

Comment: Thanks @Laurenz Albeit deleting the set, it worked, but writing function I use this as a future reference.

Comment: i have an another issue with this code dbListConnections(dbDriver("Postgres")) i am getting an error -- unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbListConnections’ for signature ‘"PqDriver"’ Could you suggest something on this @Laurenz Albe

Comment: That's something quite different.

Comment: i have raised a question kindly take a look  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76587297/dblistconnections-isnt-defined-for-postgres-drivers