# DbListConnections isn't defined for Postgres drivers

Tags: r, postgresql

While checking the connection, I am facing this issue. It works well with PostgreSQL dbListConnections(dbDriver(PostgreSQL)), but I am using it and it's not working for Postgres. What can I do?

I have tried the below two commands and they are not working:

```
dbListConnections(Postgres()) 
dbListConnections(dbDriver("Postgres"))

Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbListConnections’ for signature ‘"PqDriver"’
```

Answer (score 0):

The help page for `dbListConnections` says on its help page: "DEPRECATED, drivers are no longer required to implement this method. Keep track of the connections you opened if you require a list."

Looks like Postgres driver didn't implement this method.
So, you should keep track of the connections yourself.